# Push notification not sent to iPhone device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I get the tokenUpdate from the device, and then I try to send a push notification. But I don't think that it is working as when I send a push notification, I do not get any response from the device. Isn't it suppose to poll the server to check for any MDM Commands? Instead I keep receiving token update.

```
 String cToken = token;
            String cAlert = message;

            // Ready to create the push notification
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);



            char[] tokenChars = token.ToCharArray();
            byte[] deviceTokenBytes = new byte[tokenChars.Length];
            for (int i=0; i < deviceTokenBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                deviceTokenBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(tokenChars[i]);
            }

           // byte[] deviceToken = HexToData(cToken);
            bw.Write(deviceTokenBytes);


            // Create the APNS payload - new.caf is an audio file saved in the application bundle on the device
            //string msg = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + cAlert + "\",\"badge\":" + iBadge.ToString() + ",\"sound\":\"new.caf\"}}";
            string msg = "{\"mdm\":\"+ mPushMagic +"\"}";

            // Write the data out to the stream
           // bw.Write((byte)msg.Length);
            bw.Write(msg.ToCharArray());
            bw.Flush();

            if (sslStream != null)
            {
                sslStream.Write(ms.ToArray());
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

UPDATED: I removed the '<' from the pushmagic id

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend removing the chevrons from your mdm message to start with.

Comment: ok ive done that. but the client still doesn't respond to it :/

Comment: I'm not sure what Convert.ToByte does, but in my Java code I have:         `BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(device.getDeviceToken());

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < decodedBytes.length; ++i) {
            buf.append(String.format("%02x", decodedBytes[i]));
        }`

Comment: it's not that :/ I changed it to Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenChars) and still nothing